# OSGI bundle Exception

Tags: java, plugins, osgi, eclipse-rcp

Plz tell the solution for the below problem.when i am running the plug-in project in Eclipse  Rcp Iam getting this type error.But I added Emulator bundle to plug-in project..How to solve this problem.Please guide me.

osgi> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.rifidi.emulator; bundle-version="3.0.0"

Comment: Neil is probably right, you may not have really "added" the bundle. What the "ss" command says ?

Answer (score 0):

This means the org.rifidi.emulator bundle (version >= 3.0.0) is not active in your system.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that you added the org.rifidi.emulator bundle the only reason for still having the error is that the version is not 3.0.0

Comment: Another possibility is that he "added" it in the wrong place or the wrong way. It's impossible to tell from the question what was actually done... maybe the JAR was just copied to the project dir? Or added to the bundle classpath?